# Is that sentence true?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $f$ to have in point $x_0\in\mathbb{R}$ two different (to each other) final one-sided derivations. Then $f(x_0)=0$ is urgent (necessary) and ample (satisfactory) condition for existence of $[f^2]'(x_0)$.

Does anyone know if it is true or false ? I can't go through it, don't know how ? And if it is so, can you prove it ?
Thank you for your help :)

Comment: It's false. Consider $f(x)=x$ for $x\leq0$ and $f(x)=1-x$ for $x>0$ and $x_0=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the two one sided derivatives exists finite, and $f$ is continuous in $x$ then
$(f^2)'(x)=\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f^2(x+h)-f^2(x)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\left(f(x+h)-f(x)\right)\left(f(x+h)+f(x)\right)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}2f(x)$

This limit exists iff  $f'(x)$ exists or $f(x)=0$

Comment: Thanks, but how did $2f(x)$ appear ? From what ?

Comment: @Janka $\lim_{h\to 0}f(x+h)+f(x)=f(x)+f(x)=2f(x)$

Comment: and what does $h$ mean ?

Comment: @Janka $h$ is the increment, that we take $h\to 0$ in the definition of the derivative

Comment: $f$ has to be continuous in $x_0$, too.

Comment: See my counterexample in the comment above, please.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe you are right, I edited my answer. Thanks for pointing it out